# Did Kakashi ever love Rin or at least feel anything for her?

Tags: naruto

Well like the question says, Did Kakashi ever love Rin or feel anything for her?

I'm wondering if Kakashi ever loved or at least liked Rin. I'm wondering this because he got the Mangekyou **after** he killed her. The Mangekyou is initially awakened by the trauma suffered from witnessing the death of someone **close** to the user. Meaning someone you love deeply.

Also in the flashbacks that either Minato, Kakashi, or Obito have it shows that Kakashi was never rude or mean to Rin. Every time Kakashi was mean to Obito, Rin always tried to make him go easy on him. Than Kakashi always replied nicely to her, calming down his tone and speech pattern.

> When the people from the Rain village captured Rin and made her into Isobu's, Three-Tails, jinchuriki Kakashi went to rescue her. After he rescued her they tried running away. At one moment Rin told Kakashi to kill her. He quickly denied saying he promised Obito he was going to protect her. Later on, he was going to kill an enemy with his Chidori Sadly she jumped in front of him killing herself and traumatizing Kakashi. This made Kakashi and Obito, who was watching them, awaken the Mangekyou Sharingan.

So my question is if Kakashi ever feels anything for Rin, either loves her or at least cared for her.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you already mentioned in your question,

> Mangekyo is, indeed, initially awakened by the trauma suffered from witnessing the death of someone close to the user. However, Uchiha have historically misunderstood this criteria as the user needing to be responsible for the person's death, and for that reason they developed the practice of killing their closest friends in order to gain the Mangekyō Sharingan.

But, it depends upon each individual and the amount of trauma felt by him/her whether the Mangekyo is "completely" activated immediately, as in the case with Obito, or after some time, as with Sasuke and Kakashi.

Obito loved Rin deeply, and thus the trauma suffered by him, on watching her die, was catastrophic. Thus, he "completely" activated the Mangekyo immediately. Rin was not just a team-mate of Kakashi but also a dear friend to him who remained with both Obito and Kakashi since their childhood.  So Kakashi too had a good bonding and a feeling of friendship with Rin, but he did not love her in the way as Obito did. That's why, Kakashi too activated the Mangekyo at the time Obito did, although "momentarily", and also because of his Sharingan's resonance with Obito's Sharingan (as both the Sharingan belonged to Obito originally), as is shown in Episode No. 345 of Naruto Shippuuden:

[image]

[image]

After this scene, Kakashi loses his conciousness owing to the stress put upon him by the activation of Mangekyo. However, Obito goes on to kill the Amegakure Shinobi (Ninja of the Rain village) because of his drive of emotions deeply centred around Rin, and his complete activation of Magekyo.

Thus, you can say that Kakashi had feelings of friendship towards Rin, but not the same as the feelings of love that Obito had.

Answer (score 0):

Kakashi did love Rin, but due to his self aware attitude, having a girlfriend is less important than completing missions and working as a team.

Kakashi loves Rin the same way Sasuke loves Sakura, but being a ninja comes before having a relationship.

Comment: References would be nice..